# How to save Many to many field in Django?

Tags: django

I'm writing a function for a put request in Django. I have a many to many field and I have a problem updating this field. Here is my function

```
@method_permission_classes([IsAdministratorManyToMany])
    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = self.get_object()
        request_data=request.data
        for field in ["services"]:
            if field in request_data:
                request_data[field] = request_data[field].split(",")

        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request_data)
        print(serializer)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        if serializer.validated_data.get("avatar"):
            try:
                if instance.avatar:
                    instance.avatar.delete()
            except Exception as error:
                return Response(
                    f'Error when update Institution avatar. {error}',
                    status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
                )
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data)
    
    def perform_update(self, serializer):
        instance = serializer.instance
        instance = self.get_object()
        if serializer.validated_data.get("avatar"):
            try:
                if instance.avatar:
                    instance.avatar.delete()
            except Exception as error:
                return Response(
                    f'Error when update Institution avatar. {error}',
                    status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
                )
        serializer.save()
```

My serializer:

```
class InstitutionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Institution
        fields = (
            "id",
            "avatar",
            "name",
            "working_hours",
            "services",
            "address",
            "location_lon",
            "location_lat",
            "email",
            "is_call_to_home",
            "is_emergency_call",
            "document",
            "status",
            "comments",
            "administrators",
            "managers",
            )
        read_only_fields = ('status','administrators','managers')
```

My model:

```
class Institution(models.Model):
    """
    Pet's parasite treatment
    """
    avatar = models.ImageField(
        verbose_name=_("Avatar"),
        upload_to=upload_avatar,
        blank=True,
    )
    name = models.CharField(
        verbose_name=_("Name"),
        max_length=256,
    )
    working_hours = models.JSONField(
        verbose_name="Working schedule",
    )
    services = models.ManyToManyField(
        to=InstitutionServices, 
        verbose_name="Перелік послуг"
        )
    address = models.CharField(max_length=256, verbose_name="Institution addres")
    location_lon = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="longitude")
    location_lat = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="latitude")
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name="E-mail")
    is_call_to_home = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name="Виклик до дому")
    is_emergency_call = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name="Невідкладна допомога")
    document = models.ImageField(
        verbose_name=_("Document"),
        upload_to=upload_docs,
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )
    status_choices = [
        ('pending', 'Pending'),
        ('rejected', 'Rejected'),
        ('opened', 'Opened'),
        ('closed', 'Closed'),
    ]
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=status_choices, default='pending', verbose_name="Institution status")
    comments = models.JSONField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="comments")
    administrators = models.ManyToManyField(
        to=User,
        verbose_name=_("Administrators"),
        related_name="InstitutionAdmin",
        related_query_name="InstitutionAdmin",
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )
    managers = models.ManyToManyField(
        to=User,
        verbose_name=_("Managers"),
        related_name="InstitutionManager",
        related_query_name="InstitutionManager",
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Institution"
        verbose_name_plural = "Institution"
        ordering = ["id", "name", "status"]

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Institution(id = {self.id}, name={self.name}, status={self.status})"
```

When I call the function I get this error

`{"services":["Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received list."]}`

Print of serializer:

```
InstitutionSerializer(context={'request': <rest_framework.request.Request: PATCH '/api/v1/institution/8/'>, 'format': None, 'view': <project.api_v1.views.institution.InstitutionViewSet object>}, data=<QueryDict: {'name': ['шкмикиушат'], 'working_hours': ['{"monday":"9:00-17:00","tuesday":"9:00-17:00","wednesday":"9:00-17:00"}'], 'services': [['1', '3', '4', '5']], 'address': ['efkhjbehfbekh'], 'email': ['wolkyandex@gmail.com'], 'location_lon': ['1.863453'], 'location_lat': ['5.123744'], 'is_call_to_home': ['True'], 'is_emergency_call': ['True'], 'status': ['Opened'], 'avatar': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: _.jpeg (image/jpeg)>], 'document': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: 1468_oooo.plus.png (image/png)>]}>):
    id = IntegerField(label='ID', read_only=True)
    avatar = ImageField(max_length=100, required=False)
    name = CharField(max_length=256)
    working_hours = JSONField(decoder=None, encoder=None, label='Working schedule', style={'base_template': 'textarea.html'})
    services = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(allow_empty=False, label='Перелік послуг', many=True, queryset=InstitutionServices.objects.all())
    address = CharField(label='Institution addres', max_length=256)
    location_lon = FloatField(allow_null=True, label='Longitude', required=False)
    location_lat = FloatField(allow_null=True, label='Latitude', required=False)
    email = EmailField(label='E-mail', max_length=254)
    is_call_to_home = BooleanField(label='Виклик до дому', required=False)
    is_emergency_call = BooleanField(label='Невідкладна допомога', required=False)
    document = ImageField(allow_null=True, max_length=100, required=False)
    status = ChoiceField(choices=[('pending', 'Pending'), ('rejected', 'Rejected'), ('opened', 'Opened'), ('closed', 'Closed')], label='Institution status', read_only=True)
    comments = JSONField(allow_null=True, decoder=None, encoder=None, required=False, style={'base_template': 'textarea.html'})
    administrators = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)
    managers = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)
```

I think problem with

`'services': [['1', '3', '4', '5']]`

The most interesting thing is that I have a similar function for creating an object and everything works there:

```
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user = self.request.user
        #try:
        request_data=request.data
        request_data = request_data.dict()
        request_data["status"] = "pending"
        request_data["services"] = request_data["services"].split(",")
        request_data["administrators"] = [user.id]
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request_data)
        print(serializer)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data)
        #except Exception as err:
         #   return Response(
          #          f'Incorrect parameters: {err}',
           #         status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
            #    )
```

Serializer print from there:

```
User
You
Нет и не в этом, я не дописал приведшее сообщение и случайно отправил. Смотри если возвращаться к аналогичной функции но для создание объекта 

 def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user = self.request.user
        #try:
        request_data=request.data
        request_data = request_data.dict()
        request_data["status"] = "pending"
        request_data["services"] = request_data["services"].split(",")
        request_data["administrators"] = [user.id]
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request_data)
        print(serializer)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data)
        #except Exception as err:
         #   return Response(
          #          f'Incorrect parameters: {err}',
           #         status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
            #    )

И если тут принтануть сериализер то он выведет

InstitutionSerializer(context={'request': <rest_framework.request.Request: POST '/api/v1/institution/'>, 'format': None, 'view': <project.api_v1.views.institution.InstitutionViewSet object>}, data={'name': 'шкмикиушат', 'working_hours': '{"monday":"9:00-17:00","tuesday":"9:00-17:00","wednesday":"9:00-17:00"}', 'services': ['1', '3', '4', '5'], 'address': 'efkhjbehfbekh', 'email': 'wolkyandex@gmail.com', 'location_lon': '1.863453', 'location_lat': '5.123744', 'is_call_to_home': 'True', 'is_emergency_call': 'True', 'status': 'pending', 'avatar': <InMemoryUploadedFile: _.jpeg (image/jpeg)>, 'document': <InMemoryUploadedFile: 1468_oooo.plus.png (image/png)>, 'administrators': [2]}):
    id = IntegerField(label='ID', read_only=True)
    avatar = ImageField(max_length=100, required=False)
    name = CharField(max_length=256)
    working_hours = JSONField(decoder=None, encoder=None, label='Working schedule', style={'base_template': 'textarea.html'})
    services = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(allow_empty=False, label='Перелік послуг', many=True, queryset=InstitutionServices.objects.all())
    address = CharField(label='Institution addres', max_length=256)
    location_lon = FloatField(allow_null=True, label='Longitude', required=False)
    location_lat = FloatField(allow_null=True, label='Latitude', required=False)
    email = EmailField(label='E-mail', max_length=254)
    is_call_to_home = BooleanField(label='Виклик до дому', required=False)
    is_emergency_call = BooleanField(label='Невідкладна допомога', required=False)
    document = ImageField(allow_null=True, max_length=100, required=False)
    status = ChoiceField(choices=[('pending', 'Pending'), ('rejected', 'Rejected'), ('opened', 'Opened'), ('closed', 'Closed')], label='Institution status', read_only=True)
    comments = JSONField(allow_null=True, decoder=None, encoder=None, required=False, style={'base_template': 'textarea.html'})
    administrators = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)
    managers = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)
```

And there 'services': ['1', '3', '4', '5']. How to fix this?

I tried to give ids as int.